# Как удалить размытие текста при transform: rotate

Tags: css

При трансформации текст становится размытым, не могу убрать, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, есть решения? В Google Chrome еще более ли менее, но в Mozilla Firefox выпадающее меню становится нечитабельным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

transform: rotate(-1deg);

Comment: Посмотри еще это: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40927/discussion-on-question-by-------transform-r).

Comment: Ваш сайт через какое-то время поменяется или вообще закроется и примера кода не будет, а вопрос потеряет смысл. Чтобы вопрос не терял смысл, нужно приводить воспроизводимый пример прямо в вопросе.